# Populate form's data in modal with fragment thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring boot and Thymeleaf.I have a modal form to create/edit information:

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" th:fragment="content">
        <form th:object="${object}">

            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    &lt;!&ndash; Modal Header &ndash;&gt;
                    <div class="modal-header row">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Create/Edit</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                                style="float: right;">&times;</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    &lt;!&ndash; Modal body &ndash;&gt;
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="ID">ID</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ID" placeholder="ID"
                                th:field="*{id}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="name"
                                th:field="*{name}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="description">Description</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Description"
                                th:field="*{description}">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="date">Date</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="Date"
                                th:field="*{date}">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="other">Other</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="other" placeholder="other"
                                th:field="*{other}">
                        </div>


                    </div>

                    &lt;!&ndash; Modal footer &ndash;&gt;
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I can't place inside my index.html because the Object is null. When user click button to crate/edit user, the modal will pop-up with data.
The button is:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="triggerModal(null)">Create New</button>
```

My Jquery function:

```
 function triggerModal(id) {
        if(id==null){
            var url = "/create";
        }else{
            var url = "/create/{"+id+"}";
        }
        $('#content').load(url);
        $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
    }
```

The controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = {"/create","/create/{id}"})
    public String createObject(Model theModel, @PathVariable(required = false)String id){
        if(id!=null){
            Optional<Object> object= objectRepository.findById(id);
            if(object.isPresent()){
                theModel.addAttribute("Object", object.get());
                return "/form-modal::content";
        }
        }
            theModel.addAttribute("Object", new Object());
            return "/form-modal::content";
    }
```

This is the div tag I place on the index.html

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

I have successfully insert modal to HTML body with data loaded but the modal is not displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it.
Just place the th:fragment inside the modal class:

```
<div >
        <form th:object="${object}" th:fragment="content">

            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    &lt;!&ndash; Modal Header &ndash;&gt;
                    <div class="modal-header row">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Create/Edit</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                                style="float: right;">&times;</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    &lt;!&ndash; Modal body &ndash;&gt;
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="ID">ID</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ID" placeholder="ID"
                                th:field="*{id}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="name"
                                th:field="*{name}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="description">Description</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Description"
                                th:field="*{description}">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="date">Date</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="Date"
                                th:field="*{date}">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="other">Other</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="other" placeholder="other"
                                th:field="*{other}">
                        </div>


                    </div>

                    &lt;!&ndash; Modal footer &ndash;&gt;
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And change the div tag in the index file:

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal"></div>
```